# Cucumber-spring is not finding Step Definitions

Tags: spring, junit, cucumber-jvm

I need help!

so the following code works for me (Pure JUnit code)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/importMasterConfig.xml")
public class FeatureWrittenInJavaUsingSteps {
@Before()
public void setup(){
    /*do something*/
}

@After
public void tearDown()
{
    /*Do something*/
}

@Autowired
ItemServiceController service;

@Test
public void callingStepFunctionsExample(){

    ItemServiceControllerTestsSteps steps = new ItemServiceControllerTestsSteps(service);
    steps.I_prepare_a_X_item_for_the_X_dealer("only images and pricing", "furniture");
    steps.I_perform_the_X_inventory_service_call("createItem");
    steps.I_should_get_the_X_response_code("200");
    steps.the_inventory_service_response_result_should_be_a_X_object("Vertical Item");
}
}
```

However, when I try to run this code using the Cucumber Feature, it can't seem to build correctly. I am assuming I am setting up the project wrong.

Here is my Step code:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:cucumber.xml")
public class ItemServiceControllerTestsSteps {

//Common variables across steps - currently only local.
private VerticalItem itemToCreate;
private ServiceResponse response;

//Step specific variables.
@Autowired
private ItemServiceController itemService;

public ItemServiceControllerTestsSteps(ItemServiceController service){
   itemService = service;
}    

@Before()
public void setup(){/*Do something*/}

@After()
public void tearDown(){/*Do Something*/}

@Given("^I prepare a \"(.*)\" item for the \"(.*)\" dealer$")
public VerticalItem I_prepare_a_X_item_for_the_X_dealer(String itemType, String dealerType){ //Step function and factory in one.
/*Do stuff*/}

@When("^I perform the \"(.*)\" inventory service call$")
public void I_perform_the_X_inventory_service_call(String actionType){
 /*Do Stuff*/}

@Then("^I should get the \"(.*)\" response code$")
public void I_should_get_the_X_response_code(String codeType){/*Do stuff*/}

@Then("^the inventory service response result should be a \"(.*)\" object$")
public void the_inventory_service_response_result_should_be_a_X_object(String expectedClassType){ /*Do Stuff*/}


}
```

Here is my cucumber.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="cucumber.runtime.java.spring stepDefinitions"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <import resource="classpath:importMasterConfig.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Finally here is my Runner Class:

```
 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "rerun:rerun.txt", "html:target/local-html-report/"},
 glue = "stepDefinitions.ItemServiceControllerTestsSteps")
 public class CucumberRunner {}
```

If someone can please enlighten me why the JUnit runner works and the cucumber one doesn't I would be a very happy camper!

Comment: @JasonI read as you get build error in which line and what is the build error message?

Comment: @erhun I have made some progress in this - I was missing the @ContextConfiguration("classpath:cucumber.xml") code at top of my step definition. However, now my features think the step code is not implemented

Comment: Error says "each step" is ignored and that "I can implement the steps with provided stub code"

Comment: Now I am getting a java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but interface was expected error lol

Comment: I am guessing no one knows why this doesn't work - guess cucumber cannot be used to test a Controller class in spring :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above code, I did a few things wrong but lets cover the big ones.

1) My Glue code String was incorrect, I need to pass in the package name, not the file name (should have been just stepDefinitions)

2) I was using Spring 3 instead of Spring 4 with Cucumber 1.2.2 - The latest Cucumber requires Spring 4.

The other stuff wasn't actually related to Spring and Cucumber.

Answer (score 1):

Step definitions should be instance methods on the step definitions classes, and not class (static) methods.

Step definitions classes are instantiated (on demand) for each scenario, so no state should be leaked between scenarios.

Comment: I removed the "static" part of my step definitions and it is still failing.

Comment: Ok, so I made some tweaks to my code, and now I am getting a "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but interface was expected" error

Comment: Btw, not sure if this matters but ItemService has a @Controller tag